# DotNetNuke blog & social media integration

Tags: dotnetnuke, social-networking, browser-automation, zapier

Our site runs DotNetNuke (DNN) and I am wondering whether there are any platforms that would carry out automation of social media postings from blog posts? I know there are the likes of Zapier, but I am uncertain as to whether these actually support DNN.

Ideally, I would like to have it so that as soon as a blog goes live on our site, we can have it automatically posted on our various social media channels & automated throughout the day.

We, of course, use Hootsuite, but it would be excellent if there was a method that plugged in with this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Ventrian News Articles Module with the web service dlvr.it. This allows you to automatically post to social media from pulling an RSS feed. Really you could use any module that will generate rss but this was just always my preference, especially since you can create custom fields and template the rss feed using tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Most blogging platforms come with built-in support for [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS). You can configure Hootsuite to read your blog's RSS feed and then automatically share to social. Check out the Hootsuite documentation for more info: https://help.hootsuite.com/hc/en-us/articles/204585700-Add-pause-or-delete-an-RSS-feed